# how to iterate elements of same bucket stored in linkedlist of hashmap?

Tags: java

As we know hashmap stores all element on the basis of hashcode, in case of duplicate hashcode it creates LinkedList and store both but hashmap refers latest element when we iterate. My Question is, how can i iterate older elements?

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean older elements? When you iterate a `HashMap` you'll get all the elements. You have no direct access to the data structure it uses internally, nor do you need to have it.

Comment: Well, if you have the hashcode, filter the entries by it and loop over it.